# $G$ group of order $2p^m$, $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup, then $N\leq Z(S)$, where $S \in Syl_p(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group of order $2p^m$, where $p\geq 3$ is prime, $m >0$. Let $N$ be minimal normal $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then $N$ is contained in the center of $S$, where $S \in \text{Syl}_p(G)$.

I have shown that $G$ is solvable, meaning that $G$ has an abelian series, but I don't know how this helps.

We know that since $|\text{Syl}_p(G)|\equiv 1 \mod p$ and $|\text{Syl}_p(G)|$ must divide $2$, then $|\text{Syl}_p(G)|=1$, meaning that $S$ is the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. Now $S$ is of order $p^m$, so $S$ must be nilpotent (another fact that I'm not sure if it is useful or not). Since $N$ is a $p$-subgroup, it must be contained in some $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, so it has to be in $S$. Thus, $N\leq S$.

I want to show that $N \leq Z(S)$. I can't see how to do this directly, so perhaps I can use the minimality of $N$ to show that $N=N\cap Z(S)$. My issue is that I know that $N$ is minimal in $G$, but I don't necessarily know that $N$ is minimal in $S$.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $S$ is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup it is normal in $G$, and $Z(S)$ is characteristic in $S$, so $Z(S)$ is normal in $G$. Hence $N \cap Z(S)$ is normal in $G$.

Any normal subgroup of a $p$-group intersects the centre of that $p$-group nontrivially, so $N \cap Z(S)$ is nontrivial, and hence $N \cap Z(S) = N$ by minimality of $N$.

Comment: I know that $N \leq S$ because every $p$-subgroup of $G$ must be in a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, but how do you know that $N$ is normal in $S$? I know it is normal in $G$, but not necessarily in $S$.

Comment: If $N \le S \le G$ and $N$ is normal in $G$ then it also normal in $S$. That follows directly from the definition of a normal subgroup.